# cakephp database not saving the correct information

Tags: database, forms, cakephp

my function puts the correct value into the form for my view but doesn't save the correct value in the database. The database is saving the `accounts_users.id` NOT the `accounts_users.account_id` to my the code looks like it should be entering the persons `accounts_users.account_id`. I see the correct information in the dropdown box in the form

add function

```
function add(){

    $accounts=$this->User->AccountsUser->find('list', array(
'fields'=>array('id','account_id'),'conditions' => array(
'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));

    if($this->request->is('post')){
      $this->Template->create();

      if ($this->Template->save($this->request->data)) {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved');
        $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Fields','action' => 'add'));
      } else {
        $this->Session->setFlash('The template could not be saved. Please, try again.');
      }
    }
```

here is the add view

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->create('Template', array('action'=>'add'));
echo $this->Form->input('name',array('label'=>'Template Name: '));
echo $this->Form->input('account_id',array('label'=>'Business: ', 'type' => 'select', 'options' => $accounts));
echo $this->Form->input('description',array('label'=>'Short Description Of Template: '));
echo $this->Form->end('Click Here To Submit Template');
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
function add(){

$accounts=$this->User->AccountsUser->find('list', array(
'fields'=>array('account_id','account_id'),'conditions' => array(
'user_id' => $this->Auth->user('id'))));

if($this->request->is('post')){
  $this->Template->create();

  if ($this->Template->save($this->request->data)) {
    $this->Session->setFlash('The template has been saved');
    $this->redirect( array('controller' => 'Fields','action' => 'add'));
  } else {
    $this->Session->setFlash('The template could not be saved. Please, try again.');
  }
}
```

Comment: I changed `fields` option in your query. Kindly check and ask if it not worked for you.